How to pause function call(back) for ie intproperty value setting, which has update function?
We have ui panel with intproperty & stringproperty fields (all those below 'timezone'):

ba_props.py
all those properties have 'update=update_coordinates' function
class BastromProps(PropertyGroup): 
    ...
    async def update_coordinates(self, context):
        try:
            print(f"BA_PROPS: UPDATE_COORDINATES: CALLING bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates")
            await bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates()
        except Exception as e:
            msg = f"ba_props: update_coordinates: sweph.coordinates error:\n{str(e)}"
            print(msg)

    lat_degree: IntProperty(
        name="",
        description="latitude degree",
        default=60,
        min=0,
        max=179,
        update=update_coordinates,
    )
    ...
    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(BastromProps)
        bpy.types.Scene.bapp = PointerProperty(type=BastromProps)

ba_ops.py
'sweph.location' is before 'sweph.coordinates', it will calculate coordinates,
and populate those 9 'bapp.lat_' etc fields
class SWE_OT_location(Operator):
    bl_idname = "sweph.location"
    ...

    def execute(self, context):
        bapp = bpy.data.scenes["cosmos"].bapp
        ...
        # TODO : PAUSE update_coordinates, fill IntProperty 9x, then CONTINUE
        if bapp.coordinates_insert:
            # 'write' call to 'bapp.' will trigger 'update=update_coordinates' call
            # which calls 'bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates' = next class, which calls next
            # class, which calls next class ... which yields a ton of repeating
            # terminal prints & unnecessary code execution
            bapp.altitude = alt_result
            (
                bapp.lat_degree,
                bapp.lat_minute,
                bapp.lat_second,
                bapp.lat_direction,
                bapp.lon_degree,
                bapp.lon_minute,
                bapp.lon_second,
                bapp.lon_direction,
            ) = deg_decimal_to_deg_min_sec_dir(self, lat_result, lon_result)
        # CONTINUE
        ...
        # call next function
        bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates()

        return {"FINISHED"}

class SWE_OT_coordinates(Operator):
    bl_idname = "sweph.coordinates"
    ....
    def execute(self, context):
        bapp = bpy.data.scenes["cosmos"].bapp
        # 'read' call to same intproperties with 'update=update_coordinates' ... 
        lat = (bapp.lat_degree * 3600 + bapp.lat_minute * 60 + bapp.lat_second) / 3600
        lat_string = "sn"
        ...
        # call next function
        bpy.ops.sweph.datetime()

        return {"FINISHED"}

searching the net, py coroutines would be the way to go,
but i am having a hard time understanding this
q: which python code will prevent executing this circular code calling, so:
    first all 9 intproperty fields are updated,

    without executing call to (await) `bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates()`

    then the code CONTINUEs

    by calling `bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates()` ?


Hello and welcome. Please avoid "version tagging" your title or posts. It may give the false impression that the answers here will not apply to other versions, misleading future visitors

will keep in mind in future, thx

ok, solving that was quite simple, just did not clicked
SOLVED
make pause flags by enabling & disabling code execution
ba_props.py - add boolproperty as flag
    # bool flag
    update_coordinates_enabled: BoolProperty(default=True)

    def update_coordinates(self, context):
        # check the flag
        if not update_coordinates_enabled:
            return
        try:
            bpy.ops.sweph.coordinates()
        except Exception as e:
            ...

ba_ops.py - set & unset the flag
        # PAUSE update_coordinates, fill IntProperty 9x, then CONTINUE
        if bapp.coordinates_insert:
            # set the GODNOOOO flag
            bapp.update_coordinates_enable = False
            bapp.altitude = alt_result
            (
                bapp.lat_degree,
                ...
            ) = deg_decimal_to_deg_min_sec_dir(self, lat_result, lon_result)
            # CONTINUE -> set the GODYESSSS flag
            bapp.update_coordinates_enable = True

solved, but i didn't learn coroutines use
godspeed
